# I can't read/write a file in my Python 3.9 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, readfile, writefile

I don't know what happen, but my code doesn't want to work properly.
This is the code:

```
with open("count.txt","w+") as f:
    print(f.read())
    a=int(f.read())
    b=int(a+1)
    print(str(b))
    f.write(str(b))
input()
```

I put the "count.txt" in same directory, and this is the content of "count.txt"

```
0
```

and this is the error that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\FILEDIRECTORY\plus.py", line 3, in <module>
    a=int(f.read())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Then, the "count.txt" become blank (0 bytes).
I tried to change the mode to "r", but the same error happen, but the content of "count.txt" doesn't get erased. Then I try to change the mode to "w", change the f.write content to "1", and make the other code comment.

```
with open("count.txt","w") as f:
    '''print(f.read())
    a=int(f.read())
    b=int(a+1)
    print(str(b))'''
    f.write("1")
input()
```

But now it works! The "count.txt" content become "1"!
I also try this :

```
with open("count.txt","w") as f:
    '''print(f.read())
    a=int(f.read())
    b=int(a+1)
    print(str(b))'''
    a="1"
    f.write(a)
input()
```

And it still works!
So i think the read mode is broken, but i don't know why.
Maybe I Install Python Incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

`f.read()` reads the entire file and leaves the current position at the end of the file, so the 2nd `f.read()` call starts from the end of the file and doesn't read anything. Instead, save the read content to a variable.

In addition, `w+` truncates the file first, use `r+` to avoid this.

I'm also assuming that you want to clear the previous value in the file, so use `f.truncate` to clear the file and `f.seek` to reset the position to the start of the file.

Putting it all together:

```
with open("count.txt","r+") as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(content)
    a = int(content)
    b = a+1
    print(b)
    f.truncate(0)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(str(b))
input()
```